Read html based upon contents of a txt file
Need some Javascript help.  Here is some code that reads a text file (Current-Week.txt) with a single record and then appends the contents of that record on the end of another filename.  It then reads the concatenated filename (e.g. Standings-Week3.htm) into my page as html.
I can't seem to get this to work
<script>
async function loadHtml() {
    const weekFile = await fetch("Current-Week.txt")
    const weekNbr = await respones.text()

    const fileName = "Standings-Week" + weekNbr
    const response = await fetch(fileName)

    const text = await response.text()
    document.getElementById('elementID').insertAdjacentText('beforeend', text)
}

loadHtml()
</script>

<div id='elementID'> </div>


You're missing .htm at the end of fileName

You should use weekNbr.trim() in case the file ends with a newline.

Are you getting any error messages in the browser console? That would most likely explain why it's not working.

OOPS.   I was so focused on the javascript code that I forgot the .htm on the filename.  Once I fixed that I was in business (at least in my little test environment).  Thank you Barmer.
I'm also implementing the .trim method you suggested.  Better to be thorough.
Thanks to everyone who responded.

It's often little things like that.
